# Firebase 403 on firebaseinstallations

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm using Firebase Auth and it all works fine but I'm getting these errors in the console:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 ()

Access to fetch at 'https://firebaseinstallations.googleapis.com/v1/projects/myproject/installations/abc123/authTokens:generate' from origin 'https://foo.bar' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

Everything does seem to work but I'd rather fix these errors. Any ideas?